# count number of elements per camp

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the problem I have 2 tables city and pharmacy:

```
city_id      name         
1            city1        
2            city2 
3            city3
4            city4
5            city5

pharm_id      name      fk_city_id
   1          pharm1        1
   2          pharm2        2
   3          pharm3        3
   4          pharm4        3
   5          pharm5        4
```

I want a query that gives the amount of pharmacies asociated to that city
for example

```
   name       quantity
   city1         1
   city2         1
   city3         2
   city4         1
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: SELECT city.name, city.city_id, FROM city INNER JOIN pharmacy ON city.city_id = pharmacy.fk_city_id

Comment: add  group by city.name, city.city_id,  and add count(*) in select

Comment: GOT IT!             SELECT city.name, COUNT(*) FROM city INNER JOIN pharmacy ON city.city_id = pharmacy.fk_city_id GROUP BY city.name